# What are high performance alternatives to LMAX disruptor queues?

Tags: c, concurrency, disruptor-pattern

I'm working on a performance test of an internal C implementation of Disruptor Queues, and I would love to benchmark other similar approaches to non-thread event stream processing. There is little on Google, so any pointers or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-thread event stream processing"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Mostly, I mean I am interested in non-threaded solutions (e.g., forks, locks, etc.) Things like Disruptor Queues or other completely different approaches.

Comment: @johnzachary forks, locks, etc. imply you are multi-threading.  These features would be practically useless without threads.  I believe what you mean to say is non-blocking, not single-threaded.  The disruptor is quite a capable system when used properly.

Answer (score 2):

Queue Catalog with sources on C++ that possible can be ported to C):

http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/queue-catalog

Have already ported one of them to Scala and got better latency and throughput than with standard java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue:

https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/c92576e3b200180ee1c8ea521fb668c538f125ab/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/MPSCQueue.scala

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a C implementation here:

https://github.com/colding/disruptorC

Please notice the note about performance in the README.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out ØMQ and use their inter-thread communication transport, [zmq_inproc](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-inproc), over PUSH/PULL [sockets](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket). The communication is unidirectional but is the speediest option.